# hadoop operation only writing one row?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to process tweets-clean.txt.  By processing I mean getting the earlier date, latest date, and number of records for each user id, along with the userid itself in each row.  I'm getting only one line, with only the min and max date in that line.  What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE temptweets16 (
    date        string,
    userid      string
) ;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'tweets-clean.txt' INTO TABLE temptweets16;

INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY './hive-output'
SELECT 
    userid as userid,
    MIN(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP( date, 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy' ))) as mindate,
    MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP( date, 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy' ))) as maxdate,
    COUNT (userid) as count
FROM temptweets16
GROUP BY userid;
```

Example line of input:

```
Tue Feb 11 05:04:10 +0000 2014  1046894028
```

Only line of output:

```
\N2014-02-11 00:02:102014-02-11 00:04:100
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in 'tweets-clean.txt'? And also the output of 'SELETE * FROM temptweets16 LIMIT 10;'? Maybe the loading process has some problems.

Comment: And what's the one line that you get? Is the userid ""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify in your CREATE TABLE statement how the data is formatted, if it is a tab-delimited file you can say:

```
CREATE TABLE temptweets16 (
    date        string,
    userid      string
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```